# Is it important to have a background in statistics to learn about machine learning?

Tags: statistics

I would like to learn about machine learning but have no background in statistics. Is a background in statistics a prerequisite to get into machine learning/neural networks?

Comment: Linear algebra, statistics and probability form the foundation of machine learning. Others include calculus, optimization and graph theory. You can just jump in and apply algorithms without these, but you would not know the details of why.

Comment: i would say, definitely yes.  Machine Learning relies heavily on pattern recognition, and statistics are often needed to distinguish patterns from noise.

Comment: There is no need, in my opinion. You can learn to make a fine facial recognizer or chess player without knowing anything in-depth about statistics. But if you want to analyse or fine-tune it, statistics may help a lot.

Comment: For Machine learning you will need multi-variable calculus and linear algebra mainly. I don't think you need statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends.

In view of the prominent hidden Markov model (HMM), one needs only basics like joint/conditional/marginal probability and maximum likelihood estimation. Inference is accomplied by the Viterbi algorithm and learning (parameter estimation) by the EM or Baum-Welch algorithm. These procedures do not require advanced statistical knowledge.

In view of the learning (estimation) of the structure of, say, Bayesian networks, there is a class of algorithms that require Pearson's chi-squared test. Here statistics is inevitable.

Neural networks like the feed-forward networks or the back-propagation procedure do not require much statistics (none at all). Other models like the support vector machines require knowledge about convex optimization. So the math necessary to understand machine learning in a broader sense is quite diverse and partly deep. Hope it helps.